# print top 3 Pandas DataFrame rows to JSON

Tags: python, json

I would like to print (or return) just 3 top rows of a pandas DataFrame. Doing the following gets me all of them:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2),columns=list('AB'))
df2 = df1.sort(["B"], ascending=[True]) 

df2.to_json(orient="records")  # prints all the rows
```

How do I limit JUST the top 3 rows and print them to JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `head` and pass the number of lines to include

```
short_list = df2.head(3).to_json(orient="records")
```

Output:

```
'[
  {"A":-0.4056731092,"B":-1.2808121187},
  {"A":-0.1866904667,"B":-1.2226082762},
  {"A":0.462008584,"B":-1.070959354}
 ]'
```

Comment: Hah! As easy as that. Thanks.

Comment: yep, it asks me to wait 3 min. before I do so. :-)